# On LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE integer required error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I have a data file containing data in following format

```
asd,12,asd,asd,12,adsd,,asdas,None
```

I have a table in mysql which is has an `auto increment` int `id` and the rest of the columns as in data file.

Now i am trying

```
query2 = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'tmp.txt'
             REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
             (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9)
            """

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.db_config.dbusername, password=self.db_config.dbpassword,
                                       host=self.db_config.dbhost,
                                       database='something', client_flags=[ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES]) 
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query2)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

the error i get is

> class 'mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError'> Failed executing the operation; an integer is required

because of presence of auto increment id i tried appending `SET ID=None` as suggested by some posts,but the result was same.tmp.txt is in the same location as the script.This response is being sent by mysql server.

The `MYSQL Server is on amazon` is that makes a diff.

Any idea what could be causing this or how we can debug it?

Digged in deep.

The error comes when

```
execute method in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py is called with the query as parameter

cmd_query in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py is called 

_handle_resultset in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py is called 

read_lc_int in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/utils.py is called which return (buf,None)
```

and so `_handle_resultset` function fails.So this definitely has something to do with the response coming from server when `LOAD DATA` query is sent.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the table columns?

Comment: @Barmar they are few ints, and varchars,some date time.the date in data is already in MySQL format....so dat is not d problem

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the `LOAD DATA` command. It happens when you try to make the connection.

Comment: Please post the whole traceback in the question, you'll see.

Comment: @Barmar check update...the error has everything to do with the response server is sending when `LOAD DATA` query is sent.

Comment: Does the query work if you run it by hand instead of from Python?

Comment: @Barmar yeah from MySQL interface it's working